# Saxon XSLT 2.0 - Event Logging Changed Results Only

Tags: xml, events, xslt, saxon

I am utilising Saxon in order to batch process hundreds of XMLs and do a find and replace of values across multiple tags.

There are many instances where this process may find nothing and so will replace nothing. As a result i want to be able to output a report or event log of all instances where Saxon finds and replaces within an XML and at least output the file name as well as (maybe not possible) the specifically changed value.

This will allow me to better optimise the find and replace function. At the moment i am taking my inputted XMLs and comparing them against my transformed XMLs one at a time which does not seem efficient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to show us a sample of the XSLT that does the find and replace, then we might be able to suggest how to add templates or other code to log the changes made.

Comment: One way to do this would be to use xsl:message to generate a message every time you make a change, and then use the various configuration options available to capture the messages. (People sometimes forget that xsl:message can output XML).